# Converting Hours and Minutes to Radians

Tags: math

I just added a day and night cycle to my game, and I'm trying to update the shadows based upon the current time of day. I found some code online which supposedly converts hours and minutes to radians, but it's not working. The shadows are very jittery.

EDIT:

Found some working code, but I'm having an issue with the shadows "Freezing up" after rotating for a moment, then continuing to rotate again, followed by another freeze a few moments later. Seems like it's some sort of rounding error. Not sure what's causing that. Other than the strange random freezing, this code works perfectly.

```
public void UpdateWorldSun()
{
    float totalMinutes = ((_currentTime.Hours * 60) + _currentTime.Minutes);
    float radians = (totalMinutes / 60f) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    
    
    worldSun.RotateAround(worldSunPivot.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), radians);
}
```

[image]

Apologies that I can't get a better gif. There's size limitations for gifs.

I'm currently thinking that this is simply a conversion issue. My game is setup to accept dynamic-length of days. Right now, for testing purposes, a day is 15 seconds long. So the code that I found online to convert hours and minutes to radians doesn't account for this dynamic time-length.

Does anyone know the correct way to convert hours and minutes to radians?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event EventHandler<TimeSpan> WorldTimeChanged;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _dayLength; // in seconds
    private TimeSpan _currentTime;
    public Transform worldSun;
    public Transform worldSunPivot;
    private float _minuteLength => _dayLength / MinutesInADay;
    public const int MinutesInADay = 1440;


    private IEnumerator AddMinute()
    {
        _currentTime += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        WorldTimeChanged?.Invoke(this,_currentTime);
        UpdateWorldSun();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_minuteLength);
        StartCoroutine(AddMinute());
    }

    public void UpdateWorldSun()
    {
        float hourAndMinute = _currentTime.Hours + (((_currentTime.Minutes * 100) / 60) / 100);
        float radians = (((hourAndMinute * 360f) / 24f)) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        worldSun.RotateAround(worldSunPivot.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), radians);
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(AddMinute());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, ignore what I said about the dynamic day length. It shouldn't matter because it's using the TimeSpan. So the conversion itself is wrong, and I just need a working way to convert hours and minutes to radians.

Comment: After a bit of debugging, I discovered that the freezing takes place exactly at 0:00 every day. Which is strange, because it shouldn't be seizing up like that. It should be a smooth transition. Still looking into it.

Comment: `float radians = (((hourAndMinute * 360f) / 24f)) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;`: this is correct, provided `Mathf.Deg2Rad` has the correct value. But I would certainly add seconds/3600 into `hourAndMinute` for more granularity